# Javascript split a long file stored in a string into an array of strings based on tthe number of lines

Tags: javascript

I have looked up other solutions but none of them fit my requirement.

Lets say I have a long file with the following data in a `var str`:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

I want it to be broken into an array of 3 strings based on new line. So new array, say `var strSplit` has `strSplit[0]`:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

I want `str` to be split based on the blank line after each section of text. I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: `str.split(/\r\n\r\n|\n\n/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` your string with `str.split(/\r?\n\r?\n/);`. Check it below.

```js
var str = `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.`;

var result = str.split(/\r?\n\r?\n/);
console.log(result.length)
```